# Windows language pack update with a gibberish name

Tags: windows

This morning, I noticed that a new Windows update was offered to me. It looks very suspicious to me:

[image: Malicious Windows update]

Here are the update details:

```
gYxseNjwafVPfgsoHnzLblmmAxZUiOnGcchqEAEwjyxwjUIfpXfJQcdLapTmFaqHGCFsdvpLarmPJLOZYMEILGNIPwNOgEazuBVJcyVjBRL

Download size: 4,3 MB

You may need to restart your computer for this update to take effect.

Update type: Important

qQMphgyOoFUxFLfNprOUQpHS

More information:
https://hckSLpGtvi.PguhWDz.fuVOl.gov
https://jNt.JFnFA.Jigf.xnzMQAFnZ.edu

Help and Support:
https://IIKaR.ktBDARxd.plepVV.PGetGeG.lfIYQIHCN.mil
```

Obviously, this seems way too fishy to install, but I would like to know more. Has everyone received this update (Google only has a couple of hits for this)? Could this be an attack? Is there a way to download the update data without installing it?

I'm open to any ideas.

I'm running an Windows 7 Pro (64-bit).

As @Buck pointed out below, the update is no longer available through Windows Update. I'm not sure how this question will be resolved.

Comment: The information links looks like randomly generated domains which is a known behavior of botnets called Domain generation algorithm (DGA) used to hide the real controllers. However, the domains are NX (not registered) so either there was a data corruption, or I don't see a point. Did everybody get the same values in their updates or are these unique? (FYI, I can't post answers because it is protected)

Comment: Based on a Google search, it seems that at least some other people have received the exact same update (domains included).

Comment: There's also a thread over on [Answers about this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-update/windows-7-update-appears-to-be-compromised/e96a0834-a9e9-4f03-a187-bef8ee62725e).

Comment: “We incorrectly published a test update and are in the process of removing it.“ – a Microsoft spokesperson

Comment: The Register just issued this:  http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/09/30/windows_update_glitch/

Comment: Are you sure it wrote "4,3 MB" (not "4.3 MB")? Have you changed the decimal point to "," in Regional Settings?

Comment: The OS is installed in English, but I use the French regional settings. The decimal point is likely affected by this. Nice catch, by the way.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The official communication from Microsoft at this time:

> “We incorrectly published a test update and are in the process of removing it.“ – a Microsoft spokesperson

I won't add commentary, but will update the answer as more information becomes available.

Comment: For commentary one can see a news report: http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-accidentally-issued-a-test-windows-update-patch/

Comment: There's also an article about this on ARS: http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/09/nerves-rattled-by-highly-suspicious-windows-update-delivered-worldwide/

Comment: I won't add commentary either because it will get flagged as Microsoft-offensive otherwise. Wow. Just wow.

Comment: I'll only dub this patch: "Move over to Windows 10 or else".

Comment: It still doesn't explain the .gov and .mil domains in the patch description. I guess we will never know what really happened.

Comment: @Sebi Why would those need explanations, and not the .edu?

Comment: @Xander Any (supposedly civilian) commercial entity that conducts business with the government and military subjects itself to possibly undesirable attention and criticism. Concerning the .edu domain it may be that, due to the high number of affiliations with educational bodies around the world, a decision was made to change the functionality of software products distributed through them. As a student I had access to any MS product using a code provided by my university. The usage of the products was indefinite. Maybe, in recent years policies changed and an "update" was necessary.

Comment: @sebi: To be honest I suspect that Microsoft has an internal library with functions that can generate "random" strings, urls, numbers, etc. Such a library is really useful for certain fuzz testing applications, and just generating junk data to fill in required records you don't care about while testing. Since it is helpful if the URLs would pass any validation regexes, picking a random TLD from a list of known TLDs (such as the original handful of TLDs) would make good sense. I suspect such a library was used here, and all the URLs were generated like that.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it seems very strange to include a **.mil** domain for an update for a commercial software product. I'm unable to reciprocate the issue, but you could run the specific update in a virtual machine, close all inbound and outbound connections on the host machine(and any possible running guest machines) and monitor the update through **tcpdump**/**wireshark**.

Then at least, you could check where the update is being distributed from. Afterwards, you could check the involved remote addresses against  [black lists](http://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check) as well as their [location](http://www.infobyip.com/).

You could change the default download location of the update:

```
net stop wuauserv
mklink /j c:\windows\softwaredistribution d:\other\desired\location
net start wuauserv
```

and try to reverse engineer it.

Comment: Strange to include a .mil, and a .gov, and a .edu...

Comment: Yep, out of place and eye catching.

Comment: @Iszi I think those specific TLDs are being used here for the reason that they are unregisterable for everyone but government or military agencies and educational institutions. That way nobody can register one of those domains if an update is say, published accidentally as happened in this case.